# Looking for Documentation Pointers/Tutorials For Adding Javascript To Django application

Tags: javascript, django

I would appreciate documentation and/or tutorial links to help me with the following.

I maintain a traditional web application, implemented in html, javascript, and Perl. The web site uses a third-party open source library that implements buttons. If you wave the mouse over the buttons, they indent and put up a tool tip. The site looks very professional.

I've implemented a very simplistic Django application. It does the job, but uses hyperlinks. I'd like to dress up my Django application, and make it look more professional `a la the traditional web site.

I tried this before with some simple javascript, checking fields to see if they contained a valid answer, and this did not work. As it was explained to me, it had to do with the server side processing.

Given there is no javascript already, I have no problem using a different library (JQuery) than my traditional web site.

I have no problem if someone thinks implement in html, javascript, and php, because I've got one of those applications, too. However, I'd like to continue with Django, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript and Django are independent.  I use Django with [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) to get nice buttons but you could use any javascript library, including the one you are using in the original site.

Your existing site is either using hyperlinks, the same as Django, that are modified in the browser to be buttons (this is what jQuery UI can do as well).  This is the simple case you just need to put your javascript in the templates.

If it is a complete ajax application you'll need to write Django web services to handle those.

Your best bet is to find a tutorial for the particular javascript library you are using because Django is pretty much javascript agnostic.   For instance the [jQuery getting started](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started) page is a good place to start.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll go look at that link. When I was playing around, I was clearly doing JavaScript the wrong way, embedding it in a template.